# Does the Association Bonus count towards the Mortarboard badge?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-badges, association-bonus

Recently I passed 200 reputation and got the 100 point Association Bonus.

For the week, it says I only earned 105 reputation, then it says under my profile that I earned 210. Does the association not help? Do I quality for the Mortarboard badge?

[image: Laaaaaaaaaame]
[image: Awesome!]

Comment: Because association bonus doesn't count.

Comment: *Sooooo, do I get a badge or not?* = No, not with that association bonus you don't. Don't feel as awesome anymore eh ?

Comment: Badges? We don't need no stinkin' badges!</movieReference>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The association bonus does not count towards the Mortarboard badge.

If you ever have a question about badges, see [the full list of badges and their descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions?rq=1), and be sure to search on Meta first.

(I answered this because I screwed up my duplicate close vote; otherwise I would have just VTCed.)

Comment: It's still weird though, 25+25+25+35=110. More than what it says I've gotten this week. Not to mention, that's just for yesterday.

Comment: @The I would make a separate bug report or support request concerning that. I agree, it looks odd, but I don't actually have the time to look into it at the moment personally

Comment: @TheWizKid95 a couple of things: (1) "this week" started at midnight Sunday UTC, not midnight Sunday in your time zone (2) due to caching and other things, that dropdown for your account does not always match your reputation tab.